# restrict output of same values on dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

```
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$sql2 = "SELECT batch FROM $dept";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
echo '<form method="post" id="try2" action="pillar.php">';
echo 'Select Batch: ';
echo '<select name="batch" id="batch">';
while($q = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    $batch = $q['batch'];
    echo '<option>'.$batch.'</option>'; 
}
echo '</select><br><br>';
echo '<input type="submit">';
```

.how can i restrict the outputting of data with the same value that was retrieved from the database using the select statement? help pls! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it doing incorrectly right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not grouping your SQL-query?

```
"SELECT `batch` FROM $dept GROUP BY `batch`";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2 = "SELECT batch FROM $dept GROUP BY `batch`";
```

The `GROUP BY` clause will cause all the rows to be grouped by the `batch` column effectively only returning one row for each `batch` value.